# periodic function antiderivative

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, definite-integrals, solution-verification

I was solving a problem relating to anti derivative and integrals which is as follows:

Ex. Suppose f(x) is an periodic function with period equal to p>0 and it is integrable on interval [0,p]. prove:
$$\int_{a}^{p+a}f(x)dx=\int_{0}^pf(x)dx$$

and while solving I found a way much shorter than the one the book provided and my solution looks like this:

according to the fundamental theorem of calculus there exists a function like G that when derivated will be equal to f(x) so we have:
$$\int_{a}^{p+a}f(x)=G(p+a)-G(a)$$
now if G is also periodic we can say G(p+a)=G(a) therefor the mentioned integral is equal to zero then we calculate the second integral:
$$\int_{0}^{p}f(x)=G(p)-G(0)$$
now again if G is periodic and has the same period as f the second integral is also zero and equal to the first integral so the question is answered.
but my solution requires an answer to two questions:

Can we prove that the antiderivative of an periodic function also periodic?

if so are the periods of two functions the same?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using the word *alternating* where mostly people use *periodic*?

Comment: Anyway, an antiderivative of a periodic function need not be periodic, e.g., $1+\sin x$ is periodic, but its antiderivatives aren't.

Comment: You are being contradictive: if $f(x)$ is integrable on $[0, p]$, how is it possible to even consider the integral $\int_{a}^{a + p}{f(x) dx}$ in the first place. I believe its a typo.

Comment: Moreover, applying the fundamental theorem of calculus requires $f$ to be continuous.

Comment: well I believe the translation I've been using may have problems because the reference of this problem is written by Tom M. Apostol.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks,I changed the word alternating. could you please post your comment as the answer so that I can choose it as the answer?

Comment: @unexpected because $f$ is periodic?

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz However, OP states the function is not integrable for $x > p$.

Comment: Done, infinite.

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Comment elevated to answer, at request of OP.]

The antiderivative of a periodic function need not be periodic. For example, $f(x)=1+\sin x$ is periodic, but the antiderivative $x-\cos x$ is not.